# Tor software authenticity check on Tails USB

Tags: tails

I bought a USB flash drive with Tails already installed. If I suspect the Tor software has been altered to reduce my anonymity, how do I check the authenticity of the Tor software on Tails?

Comment: Why not simply reinstalling tails?

Answer (score 0):

Use md5 and sha256 checksums, the way you'd verify any software authenticity.

Iirc on the download page it has the checksums

Comment: with a checksum you are more or less just checking the **integrity** than the **authenticity**... https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index10h2